# Push a Value of the Selected List in an Array and Calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

here's my code at the moment. I wanted to push only or all the object that is selected in an array.

```
$('.checkbox-wrapper').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function () {
    //Use this is if you want to uncheck other checkbox if another checkbox is checked 
    //$('input').not(this).prop('checked', false); 
    var $lis = $('.list > li').hide();
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        $lis.filter('#' + $(this).attr('data-stats')).show();
    });

    console.log($lis.filter('#' + $(this).attr('data-stats')));

    var myVals = [];
    $lis.filter('#' + $(this).attr('data-stats')).map(function () {
        myVals.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
    var arr = myVals,
        total = 0;
    $.each(arr, function () {
        total += this;

    });
    $("#total").text(total);
    console.log(total)
}).find('input:checkbox').change();
```

[My JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qoa735o7/11/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong:

```
$.each(arr,function(i) {
  total += arr[i];
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9xx8qzv/

Comment: @iam--nash Mistakes happen buddy! Don't worry! `:D`

Comment: is clicking someone's answer would unaccept someone else's answer?

Comment: @iam--nash Yes buddy!

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the .on() method.

So i change `delegate` to `on`

> Html id should be unique

So i change your li `id` to `class`

And then you can try:

```
$('.checkbox-wrapper').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function(){
   var $lis = $('.list > li');
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $lis.filter('.' + $(this).data('stats')).show();       
   } else {
       $lis.filter('.' + $(this).data('stats')).hide();
   }
   var myVals = [];
   $lis.filter(':visible').map(function(){
      myVals.push($(this).attr('value'));
   });
   var arr = myVals,
   total = 0;
   $.each(arr,function(i) {
       total += arr[i];       
   });
   $("#total").text(total);   
}).find('input:checkbox').change();

$('.list > li').hide();
```

And this is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9xx8qzv/10/)**

And another **[simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y9xx8qzv/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique(),use data-id attribute instead of id

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li data-id="isActive" value="10">Item One : 10</li>
    <li data-id="isActive" value="20">Item Two : 20</li>
    <li data-id="isActive" value="30">Item three : 30</li>
    <li data-id="isnotActive" value="40">Item Four : 40</li>
    <li data-id="isnotActive" value="50">Item Five : 50</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var total = 0;
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        $("[data-id=" + $(this).attr('data-stats') + "]").each(function () {
            $(this).show();
            total += +$(this).attr("value");
        });
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qoa735o7/12/)**

Comment: yup . thanks for that . I thought that id is just the same with other attributes (e.g class) :D